# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint in MS-SQL using Hibernate when deleting objects

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

The application we have used MySQL until today and everything was fine. Now we need to use MSSQL.

A lot of our unit tests are now failing. A sample is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: 
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__field_ty__5068257C6DE5E37D'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.field_type_mapping'. 
The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, -11).
```

As I said, this test is successful when using MySQL.

The table **field_type_mapping** has a constraint:

```
/****** Object:  Index [UQ__field_ty__5068257C6DE5E37D]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[field_type_mapping] ADD UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [mapping_entity_id] ASC,
    [field_type_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The test is as follows and the exception is thrown at the last line of this test:

```
Invoice document = documentDao.get(5000);
assertEquals("Document should have exactly one reference field!", 1, document.getFieldTypeMappings().size());
assertEquals("Document should have exactly one item!", 1, document.getDocumentItems().size());

Set<InvoiceItem> items = document.getDocumentItems();
InvoiceItem item = items.iterator().next();
assertEquals("Document's item should have no reference field!", 0, item.getFieldTypeMappings().size());

ReferenceFieldType referenceFieldType = referenceFieldTypeDao.get(-11L);
FieldTypeMapping documentFieldType = new FieldTypeMapping();
documentFieldType.setFieldType(referenceFieldType);
documentFieldType.setFieldValue("a value");
document.addFieldTypeMapping(documentFieldType);

FieldTypeMapping documentItemFieldType = new FieldTypeMapping();
documentItemFieldType.setFieldType(referenceFieldType);
documentItemFieldType.setFieldValue("another value");
item.addFieldTypeMapping(documentItemFieldType);
documentDao.save(document);
flush();

document = documentDao.get(id);
assertEquals("Reference object for document not added!", 2, document.getFieldTypeMappings().size());
items = document.getDocumentItems();
item = items.iterator().next();
assertEquals("Reference object for document item not added!", 1, item.getFieldTypeMappings().size());

document.addFieldTypeMapping(documentFieldType);
item.addFieldTypeMapping(documentItemFieldType);
documentDao.save(document);
flush();

document = documentDao.get(id);
assertEquals("Number of reference object should not have changed for document!", 2, document.getFieldTypeMappings().size());
items = document.getDocumentItems();
item = items.iterator().next();
assertEquals("Number of reference object should not have changed for document' item!", 1, item.getFieldTypeMappings().size());

document.getFieldTypeMappings().remove(documentFieldType);
item.getFieldTypeMappings().remove(documentItemFieldType);
documentDao.save(document);
flush();  // Exception is thrown at this point..
```

My understanding is something is wrong with:

```
item.getFieldTypeMappings().remove(documentItemFieldType);
```

as the exception is mentioning id -11 ?

The hibernate code for removal is as follows:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})
@JoinColumn(name = "mapping_entity_id")
@XmlTransient
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public Set<FieldTypeMapping> getFieldTypeMappings() {
    return fieldTypeMappings;
}
```

As I am pretty novice with this I do not even understand what might be wrong. How can I fix this issue? Is this an issue with hibernate and how it handles the queries? I also want to mention that all the db is created with hibernate as well, no manual sql execution and db creation is made.

Comment: have you changed the sql_dialect in hibernate configuration file.? it looks like you are trying to delete parent record whose child is not deleted yet.

Comment: Pretty clear error messages _"Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.field_type_mapping'"_ references a unique constraint `UQ__field_ty__5068257C6DE5E37D`. Well, at least it should mean that a row with (NULL,-11) already exists in the table.

Comment: remove the unique constraint for one run and see what you insert.

Comment: @MitulSanghani Yes I have changed it.         <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</hibernate.dialect>

Comment: @Mackat Yes but the problem happens when I try removing something and saving.

Comment: here is the problem with is your `cascadeType` you are removing the element from your child collection and then try to save parent object with the all child collection with some of the element removed from collection please provide the sql query generated by the hibernate.?

Comment: @MitulSanghani How can I see the sql query generated by hibernate?

Comment: in hibernate.cfg.xml  add following property
`<property name="show_sql">true</property>`

Comment: @MitulSanghani I have some other problem right now I will post it once I can.

Comment: ok no problem if you want to fix temporary, what you can do is instead of removing you child element from collection take it in childObject, then get that childObject from database by get method of session using id and then remove that childObject `(session.remove(childObject))`one by one then update your parent object.

Comment: @MitulSanghani Here is the sql: http://pastebin.com/tkjDZ9Jb

Comment: sorry but i am not finding update insert or delete query in the log you posted.

Comment: just do one thing try to flush your session after `item.getFieldTypeMappings().remove(documentItemFieldType);` before you update your parent object it should work. and make sure your session is open and object is in persist mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually need the ability to have a null FK when you may not know the value at the time of entering the data, especially whilst you know other values to be entered.

To allow nulls in an FK generally all you have to do is allow nulls on the field that has the FK. The null value is separate from the idea of it being an FK. - This is what I believe you need to do.

Whether it is unique or not unique relates to whether the table has a one-one or a one-many relationship to the parent table.